# How do you handle a discrepancy in what version of graph API FB says you're referencing, and what you're actually referencing?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook says we're referencing v2.6 of the graph API currently, but
our code says otherwise.

Web: Currently on v2.8 and v2.9

IOS: Currently on 4.28 which uses Facebook Graph API v2.9

Android: Currently on 4.33 which uses Facebook Graph API v3.0

But this is what I see in the developer area on FB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVJmV.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbcZc.jpg

Looking for recommendations on how to make sense of this. I'd like to avoid scrambling to upgrade if we don't need to for several more months.